# Effective way to loop without duplicate loop

Tags: c#

I have a task to generate a file , so this is the example of data(from excel)

```
A Enr
B Cds
C Cdr
D Der
A Enr
B Cds
```

What i want is when you already found the same data, for example : The first row is A Enr, and the fifth row is A Enr, if you already loop the first row and find the same data (the fifth row) , i dont want when the variable int i = 4 , it will loop the A Enr again to search the same data ,because it already been search from i = 0 (which is the A ENR in the first row)

How to effective way to do the loop, because if you use the for statement, line 5 (A) will be looped back to check the same data, and that's the thing I don't want because on line 1 (A) has looped and found the same data in row 5.

Code Example

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            {
                    for(int k = 0 ; k < row ;k++)
                    {
                        if (fulldatadetail[i][0] == fulldatadetail[k][0])
                        {
                            if (!File.Exists(path))
                            {
                                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
                                {
                                    sw.WriteLine(fulldatadetail[i][0]);
                                }
                            }
                            else if (File.Exists(path))
                            {
                                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
                                {
                                    sw.WriteLine(fulldatadetail[i][0]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
```

P.S: sry for bad grammar, im trying to improve my english ..

Comment: show some code? we don't know what you are looping over

Comment: @KeithNicholas wait i post it first

Answer (score 0):

it linq, group by, tuple does sound familiar to you, why don't try `GroupBy`?

```
// assume index is A,B,C,D
// assume value is Enr,Cds

var result = datas.GroupBy(x=> (x.index, x.value));

use foreach then print your key, your key in IGrouping<T> now is something like Tuple. 
Item1 is index, Item2 is value.

foreach(var item in result.ToList())
{
  something.Write(item.Key.Item1);
  something.WriteLine(item.Key.Item2);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to declare an int/bool array with size according to your distinct elements (probably 22 as i see in this example),
Now, every row increase the cell corresponding to the latter that you see (e.g a[x-'A']++), also on every row do the inner loop only if the corresponding cell is 0.

So basicly just mark whenever you see a character so that the next time you see it you will know that you already saw one.

Answer (score -1):

Provided you're trying to omit duplicate rows of data, and the only check you need is that the lines are completely equal (and not just based on the first character), this code may help you. It keeps track of every found value in a list and skips outputting it if it has already been output before.

```
string path = @"C:\Some\Text\File.txt";
List<string> outputValues = new List<string>
{
    "A Enr",
    "B Cds",
    "C Cdr",
    "D Der",
    "A Enr",
    "B Cds"
};

List<string> foundValues = new List<string>();

foreach (string outputValue in outputValues)
{
    if (foundValues.Contains(outputValue))
        continue; // Doesn't output this output value twice

    foundValues.Add(outputValue);
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.Exists(path) ? File.AppendText(path) : File.CreateText(path))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(outputValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: A more elegant solution would create the StreamWriter once in a using block outside of the foreach loop.

Comment: This solution is far from effective since it's complexity is O(n^2)

Comment: If you used a hash table to record what’s been found, it would be more efficient.